# Seperate GeneID seperated by "/" in one column to multiple columns

Tags: tidyverse, read.csv

I have a data.frame with only one column of gene ids separated by "/", please see Data.

| rows | x |
| --- | --- |
| row1 | 5788/3689/5230/8826/302/79026/203068/476 |
| row2 | 3312/6892/811/3123/3122 |

How can I obtain a data.frame with only one ID in each cell like the data below Thank you very much.

| rows | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 5788 | 3689 | 5230 | 8826 | 302 | 79026 | 203068 | 476 |
| row2 | 3312 | 6892 | 811 | 3123 | 3122 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read.table` using simply the x-column as a `text` input vector and specify both `fill=TRUE` and `sep="/"`

```
read.table(text=dat$x, sep="/", fill =TRUE)
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5    V6     V7  V8
1 5788 3689 5230 8826  302 79026 203068 476
2 3312 6892  811 3123 3122    NA     NA  NA
```

And `cbind` it to either the original dataframe or to just the rows column:

```
cbind(rows=dat$rows, read.table(text=dat$x, sep="/", fill =TRUE))
#------------
  rows   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5    V6     V7  V8
1 row1 5788 3689 5230 8826  302 79026 203068 476
2 row2 3312 6892  811 3123 3122    NA     NA  NA
```

The `fill=` parameter lets read.table accept input lines with varying numbers of items per line. The `sep=` parameter allows a different separation character than the usual whitespace or comma separators.`NA`values are placed to padd out the shorter input lines. You are essentially using a single column of data to be considered as an input file to be parsed.

Comment: This works well! Thank you so mcuh!